# jQuery custom UL type dropdown: blur() does not work on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

i made a jQuery based select box.

Everything works fine except blur function on iPhone(I tested on iOS simulator on my Macbook.) it works fine on Android.
Here is what I wrote.

```
$('.listSelect a').on('click',function(e){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $('.listSelected').removeAttr('tabindex').removeClass('focus').blur().find('strong').text(text);
    //$('.listSelect').slideUp('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.listSelected').on('click',function(e){
    var attr = $(this).attr('tabindex');
    if(typeof attr == 'undefined' || attr == false){
        $(this).attr('tabindex','0');
    } else {
        console.log('Yes!');
        $(this).removeAttr('tabindex');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('focus').focus();
    $('.listSelect').slideToggle('fast');
}).on('blur',function(){
    $('.listSelect').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).removeAttr('tabindex').removeClass('focus');
});
```

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/jXTTh/

just tap anywhere outside(focus out) the dropdown list.the list doesnt want to go back on iPhone.

Any mod suggestion appreciated. Thanx!

Comment: Okay! But what is the question?

Comment: sorry i forgot to write the problem. I just edited my text. On iOS clicking outside the list does not seem to trigger blur().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) / [Blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) is only applicable to form elements, such as input, select or textarea.

What you need is [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

...or something like this:

```
$(document).on('touchend', function(e) {
    if ( !$('body').has(e.target).length ) {
        $('.listSelect').slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5J5gX/)

Comment: Thanx yckart! stopPropragation worked for me.This is final result I got: http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/jXTTh/
Though i am happy with the result, every time click or touch event happens I have to write e.stopPropagation(); for each function with click event, right?